# control not allowing an id to be recognized

Tags: asp.net

what kind of control is a cc2:WebToolkitGridview control? How is it different from a normal asp:GridView control? I am having issues adding a dropdown list within the cc2:WebToolkitGridview control, since i get an error saying the dropdown list is not defined, but it is. This cc2 is not letting the definition be recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cc2: will be a prefix that is defined at the top of your .aspx file, within an <%@ Register... %> statement.

cc1 is the default prefix that is used when you drag an assembly onto the design surface. cc2 would be the next default prefix.

You must have a .dll in your project that defines a class named `WebToolkitGridView`.  Perhaps [this link will explain the Register directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx), and help you track it down.